# Drawing a line in Animation

Tags: silverlight, xaml, storyboard

I have an invisible Polyline containing a lot of points in a canvas.

```
    <Polyline x:Name="plinePath" Stroke="#00000000" StrokeThickness="3">
            <Polyline.Points>
            <Point X="0" Y="0" />
            <Point X="10" Y="10" />
            <Point X="10" Y="20" />
            <Point X="20" Y="20" />
            ...
              ...
               ... 
        </Polyline.Points>
    </Polyline>
```

Now I need to render the line in runtime like someone was drawing it in red.  I'd like to do that in a Storyboard if I can.

Any hints on how I could do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK,

what I finally did is create my own customcontrol that has a Canvas and a Polyline in it.  My control has two main public properties :

- PathPoints (`List<Points>`) : List of all points in the path
- CurrentPoint (`int`) : Show all the points in the PathPoints that are less or equal to that number.

Now I can use a Storyboard with a DoubleAnimation based on the "CurrentPoint" property to animate my path.

Answer (score 1):

If the polyline were always heading in one general direction you could just animate a clipping rectangle attached to your *plinePath* to expose it smoothly.

*The problem you have with other methods of "drawing" it is that the individual line segments need to be resized individually along the length of their extent. That is non-trivial, but possible. There are issues over constant speed of drawing vs. interpolating X & Y that need to be calculated for each segment. Basically take the line length (of each segment) then linearly interpolate the end-x and end-y to their final position in a time determined by the line length.*